# Bulk export opportunities related to multiple contacts

Tags: reporting, contact, salesforce-id, data-export

I have a list of ~200 different contacts (and their SF IDs) and I'd like to get a CSV of all their associated opportunities from SF. The only way I know how to do so is to create an Opportunities report and creating a filter for each contact, then setting up filter logic with a bunch of ORs.  As far as I know there's not an easy way to do this with the SF Data Loader tool either. Is there a faster/better way to do this?

Comment: Why not just export all opportunities and do a vlookup in excel sheet for all the 200 contacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are the steps you could follow to export all the related opportunities for the contactId's you have.

1. Have an excel file with a contactId column which has all 200 of the contact Id's (contact file)
2. Export all the opportunities to another excel file and add it to the above contact file as opportunity sheet including contactId column on opportunity
3. Do an Excel [Vlookup](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/vlookup.html) using contactId on both sheets to get all the relevant opportunities

**NOTE:** like @davidreed suggested make sure to use salesforce 18 characters ID

Comment: Make sure to use the 18-character Salesforce Ids! `VLOOKUP()` is not case-safe.

Comment: @DavidReed  good point!

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. I'll give it a go (remembering to use 18 digit IDs - cheers @DavidReed )!